# How to stub after_create callback collectively in a model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, stubbing

I'm using Rails 3.2.11, Mac OS X Mountain Lion, Rspec

Here's my problem:

I have a model that when created, it sends the information to an api. It works all right but when I'm testing it in rspec, the test data also gets sent to the api database. Here's the code:

**Model**

```
after_create :send_to_api

def send_to_api
  api = APIModule.initialize_api(params)
  api.send_data(self.attribute1,self.attribute2)
  #connect to api, send to data to api
end
```

I tried this in my test:

```
Model.any_instance.stub(:send_to_api).and_return(true)
```

but it didn't work. Everytime i create the said model in my test it sends them to the database. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if you figured this out yet but if you install mocha you could do this:

```
Model.any_instance.stubs(:send_to_api).returns(true)
```

Just tested it and it works